# Background with opacity set is solid and not transparent in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with text and background which after scrolling down is going over the home slider.I want to have some transparency. Everything is ok in Firefox where that layer is transparent with some opacity set. But in chrome and opera it is solid and slider is not visible under. I use:

```
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

i event tried to use transparent PNG but it also is solid.[Problem preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99YU6.png)

How can i make a background transparent in Chrome and Opera?

Comment: Change the above code to background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); and see if it works.

Comment: Your issue must be some conflicting css, see https://jsfiddle.net/o17pkhgo/ - the background property does work. Your site is too complex for me to say what is wrong, especially with the slider animation making it very hard to inspect changes.

Comment: Problem was overflow:hidden;

Comment: Good to know it got fixed. :)

Comment: please html, css

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question but searching for the same problem this poped up on top for me.
So I had the same problem - working perfectly in Firefox but on Chrome no opaciy at all.
What I did and its working perfectly (at least for now) it to change from RGBA colors to HSLA colors. 
In my  case changed the following :

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

to

```
background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75);
```

I have no idea why chrome prefers the HSL colors and opacity.
Also a good point to consider, HSL colors are supported in newer browser versions.